# How can I use the force with array in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I'd like to force some bunch of signals by derived multiple instances in verilog as below.

```
integer ii;

    initial begin
        for (ii=0; ii<19; ii=ii+1) begin                                                                        
         force sydnney.top.vx1.mpg.jpg[ii].trig.be[3]                = 1'b1;
        end 
    end
```

But, I've got the below error :

```
Illegal operand for constant expression [4(IEEE)].
```

Is that impossible way to using like that?

## update

I've got some error when I use as below,

```
         generate                                                                            
          wire val;                                                                    
          genvar xidx;                                                                       
          for(val=0; val<3; val=val+1) begin : force_be3y_loop                               
          #10                                                                                
          for(xidx=0; xidx<3; xidx=xidx+1) begin : force_be3x_loop                           
         initial force top.comp.img.tc[xidx].t1c.b2tc  = val;      
         initial force top.comp.img.tc[xidx].t1c.b2tc[23] = val;   
         initial force top.comp.img.tc[xidx].t1c.b2tc[22] = val;   
         initial force top.comp.img.tc[xidx].t1c.b2tc[21] = val;  
         initial force top.comp.img.tc[xidx].t1c.b2tc[20] = val;   
    end

end
endgenerate
```

error message :

```
 Expecting the keyword 'end' [12.1.3(IEEE 2001)].
An 'endgenerate' is expected [12.1.3(IEEE 2001)].
 expecting the keyword 'endmodule' [12.1(IEEE)].
An 'endgenerate' is expected [12.1.3(IEEE 2001)].
```

Do I make something wrong?

## update2

the original concept of mine is the below,

integer ii;

```
initial begin
    for (bb=0; bb<3; bb=bb+1) begin                                                                        
     #10
     for (ii=0; ii<19; ii=ii+1) begin                                                                        
      force sydnney.top.vx1.mpg.jpg[ii].trig.be[3]                = bb;
      ...
     end 
end
```

but that is not work with

> Illegal operand for constant expression [4(IEEE)] error message.

So I'm looking for solution.

Answer (score 2):

The module portion of a hierarchical references must be constant. You cannot loop through the indexes of arrayed module instances or generate-for-loops at simulation time. You can loop through them durring the elaboration phase of compilation with a generate-for-loops.

```
generate
  genvar gidx;
  for(gidx=0; gidx<19; gidx=gidx+1) begin : force_be3_loop
    initial force sydnney.top.vx1.mpg.jpg[gidx].trig.be[3] = 1'b1;
  end
endgenerate
```

Comment: Can't I use wire in the generate statement? I've update the problem.

Comment: You cannot use a wire as a loop index. The `#10` needs to be inside a procedural block; the `begin`-`end` for the generate for-loop is not procedural. You need to explain why you need to force internal signals and what your intent is before I can suggest a more complete solution.

Comment: I need to run it in procedural block. to run coverage.

Comment: Forcing internal signals to to improve coverage collection is completely the wrong approach. Coverage is achieved by stimulus on the ports. If you cannot get the coverage you need, then you haven't applied enough stimulus or the conditions is unreasonable by design or a bug.

Comment: I know that fully understand it. but this is the only option we have.

Comment: I am a Verification Engineer by profession. I will not assist with faking coverage. You have other options. You need to research and study how coverage should be collected and the proper ways to improve coverage.

Comment: I'm So Sorry, I'll never do it again the faking coverage. forgive me please. Just give me a break.

Comment: The aproach I would use is document and waive the condition that cannot be meet in your coverage report. This way it is excluded from the coverage score and there is an explanation why it was excluded. The only time I force signals for functional/coverage testing is for error injection to validate BIST (Built-In Self Test) functionality, something I doubt you are doing. I'm guessing this is a class assignment, so check with your instructor/classmates on strategies to get the coverage you need.

Comment: Usually  How much you got the coverage at  one chip? did you have any experience?